# Trouble understanding semicolon insertion

Tags: javascript

According to [this](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons), JavaScript will insert a semicolon if:

> When the program contains a token that is **not allowed by the formal grammar**, then a semicolon is inserted if (a) there is a line break at that point, or (b) the unexpected token was a closing brace. (emphasis mine)

The classic example is

```
return  //  <--- semicolon inserted there
{
   id: 12
};
```

Which leads me to believe that a free standing `{` is not valid.  Yet the following (pointless) code alerts 2, without error

```
function foo() {
    var x = 1;
    {
        var y = 2; //yes, I know y has the same scope as x 
    }              //and that this is therefore pointless
    alert(y);
}
```

Why is the opening brace treated as an invalid token in the first code, which leads JavaScript to insert a semicolon, but the opening brace is not treated as invalid in the second—as evidenced by the fact that there is no error.

Clearly one of my assumptions is wrong, and I was hoping someone could help me understand which.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `return` statement problem you mention is not affected by that particular aspect of the semicolon insertion rule.  Rather, it's this one:

> When, as the program is parsed from left to right, a token is encountered that is allowed by some
>     production of the grammar, but the production is a restricted production and the token would be the first
>    token for a terminal or nonterminal immediately following the annotation ―[no LineTerminator here]‖ within the
>       restricted production (and therefore such a token is called a restricted token), and the restricted token is
>      separated from the previous token by at least one LineTerminator, then a semicolon is automatically
>     inserted before the restricted token.

It so happens that the `return` statement syntax has one of those "[no LineTerminator here]" quirks.

See section 7.9.1 of the ES 5 spec.

Comment: I apologize humbly for stealing an upvote with my previous, not-really-correct version of this answer.  I think the above is correct however.

Comment: As far as I know, `return` by itself is perfectly valid in Javascript, it will just return `undefined`.

Comment: @Pointy - thank you for digging up that portion of the spec.  So I guess you've been using JavaScript for more than a year or two...

Comment: @Peter: *"... it will just return `undefined`"* Yes indeed, per [Section 12.9](http://es5.github.com/#x12.9). And in the "distinction without a difference" category, *technically*, there is a difference between an explicit `return;` and execution just reaching the end of the function (implicit return). In the implicit case, the function doesn't return anything -- but the *function call expression* then handles that just like `return;` and `return undefined;` ([Section 13.2.1](http://es5.github.com/#x13.2.1)) </geekSilliness>

Answer (score 2):

The rule is like this: if there is a new line, and we have a valid statement so far, then insert a semicolon.

In your first example this is valid:

```
return;  //  <--- semicolon inserted there
{
   id: 12
};
```

In the second example, this is invalid:

```
function foo() {
    var x = 1;
    {;             // *not a valid insertion*
        var y = 2; // yes, I know y has the same scope as x 
    }              // and that this is therefore pointless
    alert(y);
}
```

**EDIT:** This answer is not entirely correct! For example:

```
num = 4 + 5
  + 1;

// returns 10
```

See comments below:

Comment: That's not really quite exactly the rule.

Comment: @Pointy It's pretty much the rule in a nutshell, can you show me a counter-example please?

Comment: That is not the rule. Counter-example: `var x = 1 + 2 [newline] + 3 [newline] + 4;` Second counter-example: `var x = document [newline] .getElementById("x1");`

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks. Fair enough. So I guess it comes down to knowing which tokens are restricted. I suppose this is the reason semi-colon insertion *should* be avoided. :)

Comment: I think a reasonable plain-English generalisation is that a semicolon will be inserted for return and throw statements, but otherwise will not be inserted if the next line makes sense as a continuation of the current line. (I wouldn't be surprised if the var statement works the same way, but I can't be bothered to look it up - and I figure since I said "generalisation" it doesn't matter. Arguably return and throw are the two statements most likely to have an incorrect linebreak after them.)

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about keywords that are expecting blocks and keywords expecting expressions - `return` isn't like `function` or `if`, that are expecting a block (`{ }`) - so the parser is going to insert the semi-colon like other keywords not expecting braces.

Comment: Well a brace is OK if you're returning an object literal.

Comment: I'm not saying braces aren't ok, but the parser won't  look on the next line for one if it's not expecting it - if you `return {` and have the object keys/values on the next line(s) that's totes cool - or like assignment operators, where `var foo =` can be on line 1, and `{ bar: 'baz' }` can be on the next