# Does the syntax (whitespace) of a javascript function return affect the result?

Tags: javascript, debugging, parsing

In writing a javascript function to evaluate a multi-variate condition, I came across what seems like a parser error in Javascript.  Please let me know if I'm forgetting something, or if this is appropriate behavior.

In my function, I'm returning the `AND` result of several variables, like so:

```
return
// a comment, for kicks
a1 && a2
&&
b1 && b2
&&
// another comment
c1 && c2
&&
d1 && d2
;
```

However, even when all of those variables have an explicit value of `true`, the function is returning `undefined` instead of the expected `true`.

I've tried several variations of returning this expression, and I've found:

1. multiline expression -- **fails**
2. expression on single line -- **works**
3. wrapping expression in paretheses -- **works**
4. setting multiline expression to *variable*, then returning *variable* -- **works**

See working examples: http://jsfiddle.net/drzaus/38DgX/

Can anybody explain why this happens?

Comment: JSLint says: `Expected ';' and instead saw 'a1'.` and `Unreachable 'a1' after 'return'.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is correct behavior. Putting `return;` in a function will cause it to return `undefined`. In your example, the line break after `return` makes the parser think this is the end of the statement, so it returns `undefined`.

Comment: dang, i was in the process of answering my own question, and you beat me to it.  i'll mark you in a sec.

Answer (score 7):

What you're running into is an odd behavior in Javascript known as "semicolon insertion". To make a long story short, when the end of a line can be interpreted as the end of a statement without introducing a syntax error, Javascript will do so. The newline after your `return` statement qualifies -- to prevent this from happening, you could wrap the returned value in parentheses, like so:

```
return (
  a1 && a2
  ...
  d1 && d2
);
```

There are more details (and a quote from the spec) at: [Trouble understanding semicolon insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393677/trouble-understanding-semicolon-insertion)

Answer (score 2):

Aha -- hooray for related links:
[JavaScript Whitespace Syntax Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549936/javascript-whitespace-syntax-error)

It appears that the parser sees a newline after `return` and automatically treats it to a semicolon.  In the cases where it works, there's either a parethesis indicating to the parser that it's actually a multiline clause, or it's on a single line (thus negating the autoinsert), or in the case of a *variable* it's treated differently by the parser.